# Share dynamic text from application to facebook - JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a web application, where I want normal button to share some text on FB using JavaScript SDK. I've tried some answers on stackoverflow, but not able to post any text, it just shows preview Image of url.

Also, on fb developer's page, description & caption are marked as deprecated. So in that scenario, what are the alternatives.

Using below method:

```
FB.ui(params, function(response))
```

Link :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic text is not possible anymore, you have to add the relevant data in the Page source, as OG Tags. If you need dynamic content, you can use parameters for different OG Tags. For example: `https://yourdomain.com/?id=1`

Available OG Tags are documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters

The "message" cannot be added, it must be 100% user generated anyway - prefilling is not allowed and not possible.

Comment: Okay, so can I add static text then? like, I want some message to be shared.

Comment: i will add information about the existing open graph data in my answer